# have gmail business account but don't receive mails

Tags: gmail, webmail

I have business gmail account, and when I fill in contact form from website in webmail/roundcube I receive mails immediately. But in GMAIL inbox no mail.

I have tried to send mail to that address from my personal email and received. Issue is that don't receive from website's form.